# How do you find another row that contains a string from the row being read and then append it

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a csv file that looks like this

```
host1,host1.localhost.com,192.168.1.11
host2,host2.localhost.com,192.168.1.12
host1,host1.localhost.com,10.10.11.13
```

I am trying to have a unique host per row which is not repeated elsewhere, so I would like to take the 1st element of row 3 and concactanate it to row 1 which same has the host name of host1.
Essentially have the multiple IPs in the same row for the single host.

End result being

```
host1,host1.localhost.com,192.168.1.11,10.10.11.13
host2,host2.localhost.com,192.168.1.12
```

Tried doing

```
row[X] if row [X] in row else ''
```

But that just appends it to the same row it is reading.
Also tried grouping which didn't turn out great.

Comment: you can use the part before the ipaddress as a key and if the key doesn't changed order (e.g. host1, host1.local.com and not host1.local.com, host1) then you can easily append the ip address of line 3 into line1

Comment: Thanks and how would I then remove the row that the key matched after appending the IP to the row?

Comment: you just write the output to a new file.

Comment: When it loops it will still read from row 3 then I'll end up with two rows of host1 in a new file?

Comment: How big is this input file? You can process all this in memory map and then write into the output file.